# Bootstrap 3 no offset classes for .col-xs-*

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The docs show `.col-md-offset-*` and larger sizes seem to work, but the offset dissapears when I shrink the viewport to the smallest size. It seems like there is no `.col-xs-offset-*`. What's the deal?

Also, the offset classes don't seem to apply to upwards, the way (for example) col-xs-4 will apply to everything. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Just too note that they will be adding in offsets for .col-xs-* in the near future. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/10554 specifically due to non responsive layouts using that grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Just take a look at the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options):

[image: Bootstrap offsets]

This is probably going to be fixed in v3.0.1, as [this pull request](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/10554) has already been merged.

Comment: Aha! Thanks. I wonder why they did that. Seems really arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your only concern and you don't want to update Bootstrap to the next minor version, then you can use my patch for `col-xs-offset-*` classes.

https://gist.github.com/dylanvalade/7362739